# Python 3: find line and skip the first match

Tags: python

I have a pretty long file in which I have to look for a particular value. The problem is that this file has two lines that starts the same way but I need to print the second one.

The file is something like:

```
... random text
Total = 910 K. #Don't need it
... more random lines
Total = 1000 K #The one I need it
```

I'm using:

```
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.find('Total =') != -1:
        Total = line.split()[4]
        break
```

But this is only giving me the first match.

How can I skip the fist match and just use the second one?

Comment: What have you tried? Why can't you set a counter variable outside of the loop and increment it every time you find a match?

Comment: Set a flag? `first_match_found = False` and then flip it after the first match, handle the logic differently.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the best solution but you could use a flag to check if you've already found the first occurance

```
is_second_occurance = False
for i,line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.find('Total =') != -1:
        if is_second_occurance:
            total = line.split()[4]
            break
        else:
            is_second_occurance = True
```

A better solution is probably to break it into a function that returns a generator

```
def get_total(lines):
    for line in lines:
        if line.startswith("Total = "):
            yield line.split()[4]

total = get_total(lines)
total = get_total(lines)
```

I think that should give you the second occurance

Comment: Seems pretty reasonable to me

Comment: Though it's worth saying that the logic goes in before the `break`

Comment: Yes! It can go into the if block so that it's computed only once

Comment: Yeah, I'm suggesting you make that clear in your code with a code comment :) at the moment, it's only in a discussion here

Comment: Thanks, I tried the first solution that you gave me and it works nice, I will try the second one and try to understand the differences. I just pretty new with python so there are many things that I don't know how to code.

Answer (score 0):

Or may be regex

```
import re
string='''Total = 910 K. #Don't need it
... more random lines
Total = 1000 K #The one I need it'''
re.findall('(Total[\s\=\w]*K)',string)[1] #will find everything related to Total
```